# Raspberry pi pico Write-Protected

Tags: pi-pico, circuitpython

I installed `circuitpython` on my `Raspberry pi pico`. I wrote a very simple code inside `code.py` and disconnected, and connected it again so I could test the code. The code worked fine but after that, I could not edit, delete or move any files because the drive was write-protected. I used the `attributes disk clear readonly` command in the  Diskpart utility to fix this problem but it did not work. Can someone please help me with this?

**Code that worked fine:**

```
import storage

storage. Remount("/", False)
def log_text(text):
    with open('Log.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(text + '\n')
log_text("Sup!")
```

**DISKPART> attributes disk:**

```
Current Read-only State : Yes
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No
```